# Does this regex mean it has to start with A, end with Z? re.search "\A[0-9A-Za-z_-]+\Z"

Tags: python, regex

Does this regex mean it has to start with A, end with Z?

```
re.search("\A[0-9A-Za-z_-]+\Z", sometext)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, those are [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

`\A` means start of string, and `\Z` means end of string. Similarly `^` means start of line and `$` means end of line.

See the [documentation for the re module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

> \A - Matches only at the start of the string.
>   \Z - Matches only at the end of the string.

Comment: @Blankman: They are equivalent if the input string is a single line.

Comment: Not quite: **^** signifies the start of a *line*, while **$** signifies its end.

Comment: Not necessarily - "start of string" and "start of line" may not be equivalent - `'Line one \nLine two'`

Answer (score 1):

What is "it"?

If you're talking about a *string*. Yes, it does: `\A` means beginning of a *string* , `\Z` means end of a *string*.

If you are talking about a *line* (inside a string), you will have to insert boundary operators:

```
"^[0-9A-Za-z_-]+$"
```

`^` ("caret") specifies beginning of a line; `$` ("dollar sign") specifies the end of a line.

If you are talking about a *word*: no, it does not; you did not specify start or end of a word.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the '\' and you will get what you want.

```
"^A[0-9A-Za-z_-]+Z$"
```